# Уважаемые, помогите, пожалуйста. Нужно ли ставить запятую перед словом «благодаря»? Если запятая не требуется, объясните почему. Заранее спасибо

Tags: пунктуация

Даже самые обыкновенные вещи в сознании человека могут быть волшебными, сказочным(,) благодаря хорошо развитому воображению.

Comment: В задании именно так сформулирован вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Даже самые обыкновенные вещи в сознании человека могут быть волшебными, сказочным благодаря хорошо развитому воображению.*

Обособление предложного оборота с "благодаря" в конце предложения не требуется.

Правило таково:

> Во многих случаях  обособление или необособление 
>   обстоятельства зависит от степени
>   распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения,
>   наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому,
>   стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление факультативно.

В конце предложения обстоятельство
 логически больше выделяется, и это затрудняет его «отрыв» от остальной
 части предложения, а потому обстоятельство не требует обособления.